# How to restrict Image size by pixels

Tags: apex, images, upload

I'm using Salesforce functionality that you upload the attachment and I'm wondering is there anyway of setting strict requirements for the upload?  Is image must be `400px x 400px?`

Comment: Is this part of a `Visualforce` upload? If so you probably want a `Javascript` solution and should likely seek answers on [so].

Comment: I'm using salesforce standard attachment upload functionality.

Comment: Here's something that may be able to get you on the right track. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're out of luck with `Apex`. This is a problem you can solve client side, but server side...not likely.

Comment: You meant to say custom vfp client side? As I said I am using standard page so I don't think I can use any client side script can I?